# Response.WriteFile

Tags: asp.net

There is one URL with specific syntax to download a file.
http://www.hddownloader.com/?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-HbxNtY1g8&feature=featured&dldtype=128

The user enters the file name in the textbox and presses the download button.In the click event the Response.WriteFile is called which sends the file to the client.

Now I want to create another website with a page, in which the user enters the filename and presses the download button to download that file.

Now I want to utilise the first URL for that. I dont want to use Response.Redirect, because by that way, the user will come to know that I am using mydownload.com.

How can I acheieve that.

One way is : When we download something from microsoft's website, a small popup window(with no close, maximise and minimise button) and then the save dialog box appears.

How to achieve this or another to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 5):

You could first download the file from the remote location on your server using [WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://remotedomain.com/somefile.pdf", "somefile.pdf");
    Response.WriteFile("somefile.pdf");
}
```

or if you don't want to save the file temporary to the disk you could use the [DownloadData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloaddata.aspx) method and then stream the buffer into the response.

---

UPDATE:

Example with the second method:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var buffer = client.DownloadData("http://remotedomain.com/somefile.pdf");
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=somefile.pdf");
    Response.Clear();
    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Response.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Hi, actually the URL is something like that "http://www.hddownloader.com/?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-HbxNtY1g8&feature=featured&dldtype=128". Filename is unknown.When I comment the appendheader and run the code with this url is throws this error:The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 

Please suggest.

Comment: @Akshay, you cannot download a file from a remote resource without knowing the url. Sorry. Not to mention that by doing this you are probably violating the remote site policy. For example you are not supposed to do this with youtube.

Comment: Hi, The URL is know, but the filename is not known. I have posted the URL in my earlier comment.

Comment: @Akshay, there is no such thing as half a url. Either you know the exact URL pointing to the file you are trying to download or you need to construct it somehow by concatenating.

Comment: The URL is not half. see my earlier comment and point ur mouse over it will be visible.You can also see my original question, I have corrected it there also.

Comment: @Akshay, the url you have shown doesn't point to any file. It points to an HTML page where you need to navigate, have javascript enabled, etc... until you reach the actual url of the file.