# Export multiple files (with different file types) from database (Byte Array) to single zipped file

Tags: c#, asp.net, memorystream

I need to export multiple files with varying file types (pdf, xlsx, .docx) stored in a database (Byte Array) and save them as a single zipped file. How should I handle the multiple files? I'm assuming I would need to first store the files in a list and using MemoryStream? I'm using the ZipArchive class to export the files as a zip file. Assuming this approach will work, I'm unsure of how to pass the list as an argument to the ZipArchive (DownloadMultipleFiles) method.

```
protected void lnkExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string applicationID = ((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
    var myList = GetFilesandConvertToList(applicationID);
    DownloadMultipleFiles(myList); //How would I pass myList as an argument here? Obviously, this would not work.
}
```

Call stored procedure to get the files and place them in a list:

```
public List<ZipList> GetFilesandConvertToList(string applicationID)
{           
    List<ZipList> fileList = new List<ZipList>();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spGetFilesByID", ConnC.con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApplicationID", applicationID); //This will return several files (different file types using the ID)
    ConnC.con.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (sdr.HasRows)
        {
            while(sdr.Read())
            {
                ZipList zl = new ZipList();
                sdr.Read();
                zl.bytes = (byte[])sdr["FILE_CONTENT"];
                zl.contentType = sdr["FILE_TYPE"].ToString();
                zl.fileName = sdr["FILE_NAME"].ToString();
                fileList.Add(zl);
            }                    
         }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

Using ZipArchive to place the list in a MemoryStream and export as a zip file:

```
public void DownloadMultipleFiles(List<byte[]> byteArrayList)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            foreach (byte[] file in byteArrayList)
            {
                ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.CreateEntry(file.fileName + ".pdf", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
                using (Stream zipStream = entry.Open())
                {
                    zipStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
                }
            }
        }
        return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip", "Archive.zip");
    }
}
 
public class ZipList
{
    internal byte[] bytes;
    internal string contentType;
    internal string fileName;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** I've updated this method with a slightly modified answer from @Andy. This works great:

```
protected void lnkExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string applicationID = ((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
    var myList = GetFilesandConvertToList(applicationID);
    //Download Zipped File
    byte[] fileBytes = GetZipFileForApplicationId(applicationID);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Application.zip");
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");
    Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

Using the method suggested from @Andy to get the files into a memory stream and return a byte array:

```
public byte[] GetZipFileForApplicationId(string applicationID)
{
    byte[] fileBytes = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spGetFilesByID", ConnC.con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApplicationID", applicationID);
    ConnC.con.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (sdr.HasRows)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        byte[] bytes = (byte[])sdr["FILE_CONTENT"];
                        string contentType = sdr["FILE_TYPE"].ToString();
                        string fileName = sdr["FILE_NAME"].ToString();

                        ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.CreateEntry(fileName);
                        using (Stream zipStream = entry.Open())
                        {
                            zipStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        }
                    }
                }
                ms.Position = 0;
                fileBytes = ms.ToArray();

            }
        }
    }
    return fileBytes;
}
```

Comment: @DaleK When I try ```DownloadMultipleFiles(List<ZipList>);``` I get ```...is a type, which is not valid in the given context.```

Comment: I've edited your question back to contain its original content, because otherwise the answers provided make no sense. On this site you need to ask one clear question, and then don't fundamentally change it again once people have posted answers. And if you want to show us the code you ended up using, post your own answer because then its still clear to future readers what the question itself was and what the possible answers are. You also shouldn't use a question as a debug session, if you have another question then ask another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could kill a couple birds with one stone and do it all at once without extra models (this hasn't been tested, but you'll get the gist):

```
public byte[] GetZipFileForApplicationId(string applicationID)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spGetFilesByID", ConnC.con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApplicationID", applicationID);
    ConnC.con.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (sdr.HasRows)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    while(sdr.Read())
                    {
                        var bytes = (byte[])sdr["FILE_CONTENT"];
                        var contentType = sdr["FILE_TYPE"].ToString();
                        var fileName = sdr["FILE_NAME"].ToString();
                        
                        var entry = archive.CreateEntry(fileName);
                        using (var zipStream = entry.Open())
                        {
                            zipStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        }
                    } 
                }
                ms.Position = 0;
                // This is kind of redundant. You should return the
                // MemoryStream object instead of duplicating it's data.
                // I'll let you play with that.
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: this gets me very close. Using your example (slightly modified - see my original post), how would I return the bytes in order to download the file?

Comment: @Shane -- take a look at all the answers for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778941/asp-c-sharp-send-file-to-client

Comment: A few minor modifications fixed it (I've updated my original post). Thank you it works great!.

Comment: @Shane -- awesome job. i love it when a plan comes together.

Answer (score 2):

Its seems you were mostly there, in fact I think you needed to use `List<ZipList>` because your `byteArrayList` doesn't contain a definition for fileName`or`Length`.

```
public void DownloadMultipleFiles(List<ZipList> zipList)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            foreach (var file in zipList)
            {
                ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.CreateEntry(file.fileName + ".pdf", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
                using (Stream zipStream = entry.Open())
                {
                    zipStream.Write(file.bytes, 0, file.bytes.Length);
                }
            }
        }
        // Currently method returns void?
        // return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip", "Archive.zip");
        // Maybe you want
        File.WriteAllBytes("application/zip/Archive.zip", ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: This did answer one of my original questions, regarding how to pass the list as an argument, however, I've modified my original post to hopefully clear up the confusion about what I'm trying to accomplish (return a zipped file) and to do as @Andy suggested (kill a couple of birds with one stone).